# Grok pattern for the following log4j pattern

Tags: log4j, logstash-grok, grok

How to construct the grok pattern for the following log4j pattern?

%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a pattern and posing as a reference for others.

```
match => { "message" => "%{TIME:Time}\s* %{LOGLEVEL:LogLevel}?\s* %{DATA:Thread}?\s*: %{GREEDYDATA:Message}?\s*"}
```